# flutter error assertion failed !_Debug locked is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
if (_username == _password) {
  Navigator.of(ctx).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (ctx1) => const HomeScreen()
    ),
  );
```

while writing this navigator code there is no issue but when i run it , it shows an error like failed assertion !_debug locked is not true.

> Error: Assertion failed:
> ..\…\widgets\navigator.dart:3029
>
> !navigator._debugLocked
> is not true

and not only one error for me two errors are there the second error was like this

> Error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.

Comment: Can you include more snippet before placing this `if` statements?

Comment: ok i will add it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and remove `const` keyword, read `pushReplacement` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html)

your two variables

```
var userName = 'ok';
var passWord = 'ok';
```

Your Condition with widget:

```
 TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (userName == passWord) {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Text(
              'Login',
            ),
          ),
```

Your HomeScreen class/widget.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('object');
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Placeholder(),
    );
  }
}
```